# Environment.SpecialFolder is Returning Empty String in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get a database connected to my Xamarin application. My database (.db3) file is in the Local AppData folder. `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` is returning an empty string. In fact, I tried all the special folder enum values, and I'm not getting anything returned for either of them. I saw another way to get the path with `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` which also returned an empty string for me. The other solutions I saw on StackOverflow were no help (setting the Load User Profile to true in IIS manager, etc.). Are there any configurations I may be missing in Visual Studio? If not, how can I get these to work?

Comment: which platform are you testing this on?  Why would an IIS Manager setting have any possible relation to this problem?

Comment: I checked the code you provided `var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);`. It would be able to get the path. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/SZVu6l4 We need more details to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

**Get appdata file path c#**

```cs
var path =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

For more detail check this article:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/370232/Where-Should-I-Store-My-Data